# Windows phone emulator not being started

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-8.1, windows-update

I am facing a strange issue with Windows Phone Emulators for last a few days. When I try to run any windows phone application from Visual Studio 2013/2012, it initially starts the emulator and then stops with an error displayed in the error window inside visual studio:

```
Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': 
SmartDeviceException - App deployment failed. Please try again.
```

I have been trying many solutions in order to fix this issue but nothing helped. At last I re-installed the whole windows 8.1 and then visual studio 2013. Then I created a windows phone 8 application and run it smoothly in windows phone emulator.

Then I installed all windows updates including windows 8.1 update 1. After that I installed the visual studio 2013 update 2. Now if I run any new/existing windows phone 8/8.1 project I get the same error again. Seems like there is something wrong with windows 8.1 updates or visual studio 2013 update 2.

Any help?

Comment: How much memory do you have left on your main HDD. I had this issue once because I had less than a gig left. You can also try opening up the HyperV manager and deleting the emulators it has created. When you start the emulator again it will rebuild them.

Comment: My C drive, where Windows is installed, has 214 GB free. Moreover I have first defragmented my disk and then re-installed everything including my windows OS. So everything is new and fresh.

Comment: Hmm sounds like you broke it then.

Comment: :) Do you find anything mentioned in my question which could break the emulators? In order to fix this issue i have re-installed my entire windows OS with updates + VS with update 2. And the issue remains as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling the symantec antivirus fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open network and sharing center
2. Change adapter settings
3. Check if vEthernet  [Windows phone emulator internal switch is enabled)
4. Try deploying it to the emulator now

If above does not work

1. Delete the virtual switch(s) if any and do a deployment
2. If it still does not work, connect to the internet via a LAN
3. Keep you’r wifi on
4. do a deployment to the emulator

Most cases above method worked !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when i tried switching the target OS version of my app from Windows Phone 8 to 8.1. With 8.1 you get a new manifest file and if, for app or publisher identification string, you have different values in one manifest file than in the other, it will output that exact error when trying to start the app in the emulator. However after searching the web back when i had that error, this error seems to have quite a bunch of possible sources, this being only one among many other, but be sure to check it.